# Nginx - 301 redirect www and non-www to https-non-www not working

Tags: redirect, nginx, https, http-status-code-301

The redirection I made from www and non-www to the https-non-www uri of my web site doesn't work.

Here my server block :

```
server {
       listen           80;
       listen           [::]:80;
       server_name      gfelot.xyz www.gfelot.xyz;
       return           301 https://gfelot.xyz$request_uri;
}

server {
       listen           443 ssl http2 default_server;
       listen           [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
       include          snippets/ssl-gfelot.xyz.conf;
       include          snippets/ssl-params.conf;

       server_name      gfelot.xyz;

       access_log       /var/log/nginx/gfelot.xyz.access.log;
       error_log        /var/log/nginx/gfelot.xyz.log;

       root /var/www/html;
       index index.html index.htm

       error_page       404 /404.html;
       error_page       500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

       location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
       }

       location ~* \.css$ {
                 access_log off;
                 expires 1M;
                 add_header Pragma public;
                 add_header Cache-Control public;
                 add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
       }
}
```

include ssl-gfelot.xyz.conf :

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/gfelot.xyz/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/gfelot.xyz/privkey.pem;
```

include ssl-params.conf :

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
# Disable preloading HSTS for now.  You can use the commented out header line that includes
# the "preload" directive if you understand the implications.
#add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
   listen           80;
   listen           [::]:80;
   server_name      gfelot.xyz www.gfelot.xyz;
   return           301 https://gfelot.xyz$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen           443;
   server_name      gfelot.xyz;

   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate  < your ssl file ssl-xyx.crt path>;
   ssl_certificate_key <ssl keyfile.key path>;
   access_log       /var/log/nginx/gfelot.xyz.access.log;
   error_log        /var/log/nginx/gfelot.xyz.log;

   root /var/www/html;
   index index.html index.htm

   error_page       404 /404.html;
   error_page       500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

   location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   }

   location ~* \.css$ {
             access_log off;
             expires 1M;
             add_header Pragma public;
             add_header Cache-Control public;
             add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
   }
}
```

Comment: I may forget to show you the files I got in my include but it's to ssl certif file.
I will edit my post.

Comment: please set your correct ssl path & like my post as well

Comment: I put the path of my file inside the include. so it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Why are you using include within file?

Comment: to have a clean conf file. But even copy/paste your conf with the good path it's not working.

Comment: Also I follow this tutorial :
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Kindly see this article within your link 'Create a Configuration Snippet Pointing to the SSL Key and Certificate'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122583/discussion-between-ragnar-and-ashish-gupta).

Comment: share your facebook or whatsup number for future concern.

Comment: accept my message over facebook: facebook.com/ashu.tanishq